# What mini games in mii plaza give you hats?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza

I'm thinking about buying the extra mini games that you can purchase in mii plaza.  Can they potentially give you additional hats?  It's not the definite deciding factor, but it's definitely a point in their favor.

Additionally, if they **do** give you hats, are they unique to these games in that I can't get them in any other games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The individual games earn you Plaza Tickets for doing various things (which vary per game), and you can use these tickets to buy different hats and outfits (they change daily) - without buying these games, there are many hats and outfits you cannot get.

The games themselves don't give you hats, per se, but each one has activities you have to complete (think of them similar to achievements) in order to earn tickets, tickets get you hats from the Exchange Booth (unlocked when you buy one or more of the games).

Comment: Is the ticket booth unique to each sub-game or is it another mii-plaza sub-section (similar to how you select the games)?  Are the tickets game specific or a unified currency?

Comment: It is a mii plaza subsection, and the tickets are a unified currency across all the games.